# Закроют ли приложение с названием "Android Clicker" или "Андроид кликер"?

Tags: google-play

Если название в Google Play будет "Android Clicker", то приложение закроют из-за нарушения? И если да, то как сделать чтобы не закрыли? И тот-же вопрос с названием "Андроид кликер".

P.S. Кликер про андроид, а не для андроид, просто мне уже говорили "Clicker for Android". И да, я читал [правила использования бренда](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/brand-guidelines?hl=ru), но я ничего не понял.

Comment: Недавно игра вышла про Андроидов,если гугл в суд на них не подала,то все ок)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Слово Android и любые другие слова, похожие на Android до степени смешения, нельзя использовать в названиях приложений или устройств, включая телефоны, планшеты, телевизоры, динамики, наушники, часы и т. д. Вместо этого используйте словосочетание "для Android".

Comment: А слово "андроид" тоже считается?

Comment: Степень смешения товарных знаков — это такой уровень схожести товарных знаков, при котором они ассоциируются друг с другом и, тем самым, могут ввести потребителей в заблуждение. Так что "андроид" тоже считается.

Comment: Ок, тогда если в игре присутствует робот андроид?

Comment: @ilemontree придумайте другое название. Например Robot Clicker.

Comment: спасибо. Тогда за сам логотип андройда (зеленый робот) блокируют?

Comment: @ilemontree об этом тоже написано в правилах использования бренда. Логотип вы использовать можете, но надо указать авторство.